# Perfect matchings in infinite regular bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, matching-theory, perfect-matchings, incidence-geometry

This question was motivated by a discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375792/injective-choice-function-for-infinite-complete-linear-hypergraphs) and is related to a previous question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287380/perfect-matchings-in-infinite-graphs?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Let $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ be cardinals such that $0<\lambda\leq \kappa$.  Let $G=(A\cup B, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $|A|=\kappa=|B|$ such that every vertex has degree $\lambda$.  Does $G$ have a perfect matching?

If so, it would in particular imply that a (non-degenerate) projective plane $(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{L})$ has a bijection $f:\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{P}$ such that $f(e)\in e$ for all $e\in \mathcal{L}$ without having to first prove that if $|\mathcal{P}|$ is infinite then $|e|=|\mathcal{P}|$ for all $e\in \mathcal{L}$.

Comment: I love this generalization of my question, @louisd!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is correct (assuming $\lambda\gt0$).

If $\lambda$ is infinite then each connected component of $G$ has $\lambda$ vertices. Since the components can be handled independently, the problem reduces to the $\kappa=\lambda$ case, which can be done by a straightforward transfinite recursion.

If $\lambda$ is a positive integer, this is a classical theorem. First, the existence of a matching of $A$ *into* $B$ follows by the usual sort of compactness argument (e.g. Tychonoff's theorem) from the fact that every finite subset of $A$ can be matched into $B$, which is a famous result of graph theory with many names. Then, givem a matching of $A$ into $B$ and a matching of $B$ into $A$, we can get a perfect matching from Banach's mapping theorem, which says: Given any two mappings $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, there are partitions $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and $B=B_1\cup B_2$ such that $f(A_1)=B_1$ and $g(B_2)=A_2$.

Comment: You said "if $\lambda$ is infinite then each connected component of $G$ has $\lambda$ vertices.  But this seems to imply that if $\lambda<\kappa$, then $G$ is disconnected.  Is that true?

Comment: Yes. In a $d$-regular graph, the number of verticeswithin a distance at most $n$ from $v_0$ is at most $1+d+d^2+\cdots+d^n$. If $d$ is infinite then $1+d+d^2+\cdots$=d$. Assuming the axiom of choice, of course.

Comment: As someone who usually only thinks about finite graphs and occasionally countably infinite graphs, I somehow never encountered this fact.  While it seems obvious to me now that you point it out, I found this surprising at first. Thanks.