# Transversal of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$

Tags: set-theory, permutations, infinite-combinatorics

**Motivation.** I am trying to make an interesting infinite version out of this fascinating problem from the Russian mathematical olympiad:

> There are $c$ flavours of cookies, we are given $n$ cookies of each flavour. The $c\cdot n$ cookies are put into $c$ boxes, each box containing $n$ cookies. Prove that we can select one cookie from each box such that the selection contains a cookie from each flavour.

Let $f:(\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N\times\N)\to \N$ be a map with the following properties:

1. For all $n\neq n'\in \N$ we have $\{f(n,k):k\in \N\}\neq \{f(n',k):k\in\N\}$, and
2. For all $n\in\N$ the set $L_n := \big\{i\in\N: \big(\{i\} \times \N\big) \cap f^{-1}(\{n\}) \text{ is infinite}\big\}$ is infinite.

If $c:\N\to\N$ is a map, the *transversal map* of $c$ with respect to $f$ is defined by $t_{(f,c)}(n) = f\big(n, c(n)\big)$ for all $n\in \N$.

**Question.** If $f:\N\to\N$ has the property defined above, is there a map $c:\N\to\N$ such that $t_{(f,c)}$ is a bijection?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, will try to make this a meaningful question.

Comment: Does not usual back and forth method work? If finitely many images and preimages of our further transversal bijection are already defined, we may add yet another image and yet another preimage preserving injectivity

Comment: You're looking for an infinite version of Hall's Marriage Theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. Define $f(0,k)=0$, $f(1,k)=1$, and $f(n,k)=k\operatorname{mod}n$ for $n\ge2$. Your conditions are satisfied, and a transversal map $t=t_{(f,c)}$ can't be injective since $t(0)=0$, $t(1)=1$, and $t(2)\in\{0,1\}$.

The nicest generalization of that "Russian olympiad problem" that I know of is this classical theorem of D. Kőnig:

**Theorem.** If $n$ is a positive integer, then every $n$-regular bipartite multigraph (finite or infinite) has a perfect matching. (And so it has a $1$-factorization.)

In the olympiad problem, the vertices are "boxes" and "flavours", and each "cookie" is an edge joining a "box" to a "flavour". There may be multiple edges, as a box may contain several cookies of the same flavour. And of course in the olympiad problem the multigraph is assumed to be finite.

Let me sketch a proof of Kőnig's theorem. Call the partite sets $A$ and $B$. By Hall's "marriage theorem" we can find a matching that covers any given finite subset of $A$. Then we can use the compactness of the Tychonoff product space $\prod_{a\in A}N(a)$ to get a matching $M_1$ that covers $A$. Likewise there is a matching $M_2$ that covers $B$. To extract a perfect matching from $M_1$ and $M_2$ we use Banach's refinement of the Cantor–Bernstein theorem:

**Theorem.** Given any maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, we can find sets $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ such that $A=A_1\cup A_2$, $B=B_1\cup B_2$, $A_1\cap A_2=B_1\cap B_2=\varnothing$, and $f[A_1]=B_1$ and $g[B_2]=A_2$.

**P.S.** For *simple* graphs, the condition "$n$ is a positive integer" in Kőnig's theorem can be weakened to "$n$ is a nonzero cardinal number, finite or infinite"; see the old question [Perfect matchings in infinite regular bipartite graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375823/perfect-matchings-in-infinite-regular-bipartite-graphs).